# Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, setstate

I'm doing a sorting for a table, it should sort the columns alphabetically, reverse alphabetically and get back to original form for each time the method is called.

Here is my code:

```
export default class GenericTable extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      otherStudd: '',
      currentSort: 'default',
          rows: this.props.rows, // I receive the rows data on props        
       };
    }

  onSortChange = index => {
    const sortMap = {
      default: 'up',
      up: 'down',
      down: 'default',
    };

    const { currentSort, currentIndex } = this.state;

    const nextSort = currentIndex === index ? sortMap[currentSort] : 'default';

    const newRows = [...this.state.rows]; // line 40 - here is the error

    switch (nextSort) {
      case 'up':
        newRows.sort((a, b) => (a.cells[index] <= b.cells[index] ? -1 : 1));
        break;
      case 'down':
        newRows.sort((a, b) => (b.cells[index] <= a.cells[index] ? -1 : 1));
        break;
    }

    this.setState({
      rows: newRows,
      currentSort: nextSort,
      currentIndex: index,
    });
  };

...

}
```

I think that the code looks correct but I get an es-lint error message:

```
 Line 40:25:  Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state  react/no-access-state-in-setstate
```

It should be done a callback function but I don't know how to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see where you consume your state of `rows`?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with doing a shallow copy of the state with the spread operator as such `const newRows = [...this.props.state];`. What is forbidden is directly mutating `state` without setState()`

Comment: `this.props.rows` and `this.state.rows` are **NOT** the same thing. You're using the one in the props and that's why you are getting the warning saying that the one in the state is not being used.

Comment: so I replaced it `const newRows = [...this.state.rows];` and now there is a new error: `Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state  react/no-access-state-in-setstate` for that line

Comment: @LeoMessi that's an entirely different problem that you can read about [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-access-state-in-setstate.md). You can solve it by providing a function to `setState` instead of an object, just as mentioned in the link I pasted.

Comment: This last error happens because you are making a copy of state, then modify state value and, due to setState being async, is bad as you may overwrite state

Comment: I read that it should use a callback function. So something like `function myCallBack() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({rows: prevState.newRows}));
  }` ?

Comment: Yes, you need an update function like `this.setState(prevState => /*here set new state based on prevState*/)`

Comment: I don't understand how to do that... if you could post an answer with that it would be really helpful

Comment: @LeoMessi please update your question with the new issue described here in the comments, otherwise, an answer would make no sense given the current state of the question.

Comment: At the time when i answer your question it was completely different and it was about an unused field error. After submitting it, i realize it and updated my answer too.

Comment: @nostromo821 it wasn't me who downvoted your answer :) so I replaced my `this.setState(...)` with yours and the above remained unchanged. that's how you would do it right? If so, I don't know why I get this error now: `currentIndex' is already declared in the upper scope` not only for currentIndex but also for currentSort, nextSort and newRows

Comment: @LeoMessi you should completely move your function logic into new setstate callback function. So remove the old part of your declarations in the onSortChange method and make sure there is no duplicate code inside and outside your callback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a setState with callback function that does the data processing and set the new state for you.

Here is a converted version for your case:

```
  onSortChange = index => {
     const sortMap = {
      default: 'up',
      up: 'down',
      down: 'default',
  };

  this.setState(({ rows, currentIndex, currentSort }) => {

    const nextSort = currentIndex === index ? sortMap[currentSort] : 'default';

     const newRows = [...rows];

      switch (nextSort) {
       case 'up':
       newRows.sort((a, b) => (a.cells[index] <= b.cells[index] ? -1 : 1));
       break;
      case 'down':
      newRows.sort((a, b) => (b.cells[index] <= a.cells[index] ? -1 : 1));
      break;
      default: break;
      }

      return {
        rows: newRows,
        currentSort: nextSort,
        currentIndex: index,
      };
  });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could try an approach like this:

```
orderRows = (data, index, nextSort) => {
    switch (nextSort) {
      case 'up':
        data.sort((a, b) => (a.cells[index] <= b.cells[index] ? -1 : 1));
        break;
      case 'down':
        data.sort((a, b) => (b.cells[index] <= a.cells[index] ? -1 : 1));
        break;
    }
    return data;
}

onSortChange = index => {
    const sortMap = {
      default: 'up',
      up: 'down',
      down: 'default',
    };

    const { currentSort, currentIndex } = this.state;

    const nextSort = currentIndex === index ? sortMap[currentSort] : 'default';

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      rows: this.orderRows(prevState.rows, index, nextSort),
      currentSort: nextSort,
      currentIndex: index,
    }));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning props to the state and using them from therer is a React anti-pattern (you can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)).

When the scenario you are trying to achieve requires that, the recommended way is to create a fully controlled component, or in this case, a partially controlled component where, not only `rows` are used from the props, but any transformation on them is also done through the props (in this case, sorting).

The snippet below demonstrates a simplified version of the issue at hand. We create a `Parent` component that stores `rows` in its state, and also provides a method that performs the sort. It then renders a fully controlled `Child` component that doesn't need to have its own state and receives the rows as well as its sorter function as props instead.

The `sortRows` method illustrates how to use `setState` with a callback that offers the benefit of producing more consistant results on the state compared to providing a state object instead.

```js
class Child extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        const { rows, sortRows } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>{ rows.map((row, i) => (<li key={ i }>{ row }</li>)) }</ul>
                <button onClick={ () => { sortRows(true) }}>Sort Ascending</button>
                <button onClick={ () => { sortRows(false) }}>Sort Descending</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class Parent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rows: ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter']
        };
    }

    sortRows = (isSortAscending) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            rows: prevState.rows.slice().sort((a, b) => {
                if (a < b) return -(isSortAscending ? 1 : -1);
                if (a > b) return (isSortAscending ? 1 : -1);
                return 0;
            })
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return <Child rows={ this.state.rows } sortRows={ this.sortRows } />;
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's an antipattern but lets say this.props never changes (it's used just to pass data from parent to child). In this case (and only in this case) copy props into state could be considered an acceptable solution?

Comment: If the prop never changes, you can simply use it directly from the props, there is no need to put it in the state, it adds no value.